# How to get alerted if a secret changes in Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, alert, azure-keyvault

I would like to get alerted if the value of a secret on my KeyVault was updated. However, after performing this action, I didn't see any logs in neither the associated Log Analytics nor the Activity Logs of the KeyVault corresponding to the secret value update.

Anyone knows a way to get alerted in this situation?

Comment: Have you enabled Key Vault logs in Diagnostic Settings?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/howto-logging?tabs=azure-portal

Normally, after it, you should see SecretUpdate actions in logs dedicated to Key Vaults.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Secrets#operation-names-table

Comment: have you tried eventgrid integration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-logicapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I agree with @Thomas to get an alert when secret values changes you can make use of eventgrid.*

I tried in my environment created key vault with secret like below:

[image]

In keyvault -> event -> logic Apps -> sing-in with your account -> Add Resource Type -> `Microsoft.KeyVault.vaults`  and Event Type Item -> `Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNewVersionCreated` and additionally you can use `Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry`

[image]

Choose an operation type email -> choose send an email(v2) -> Add your email address like below: |

[image]

Now when key vault secret values or key vault secret updated alert triggered successfully like below:

[image]